# Measure Execution Time on Page Cache layer Android

Tags: android, linux, kernel

I want to measure the execution time spend on the Page Cache layer for an app. However, since I am a beginner in the field of Linux kernel in the Android, I don't know of any tool that could help me in this process. As far as I know , **Systrace** or **fTrace** can be used to extract this information but it requires sufficient domain knowledge about the kernel.

If there are any tools present or certain ADB commands that can help me with the extraction, please let me know.

Thanks !

I tried extracting the Ftrace logs but they are complicated for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

To measure the execution time spent on the Page Cache layer for an app in the Linux kernel on Android, you can use the following tools and approaches:

-Cachestat is a tool that provides cache statistics in Linux. It can be used to measure page cache activity. To install cachestat, you can use the perf-tools, which is a part of the linux-tools library. Here are the steps to install and run cachestat:

**sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/master/fs/cachestat
chmod +x cachestat
sudo ./cachestat**

Comment: thanksss @Climax, I will check it up soon and will let you know !!